# Mapbox how to return a GeoJSON from tendered features

Tags: geojson, mapbox

I have a map of winter sports mountains that displays on a map perfectly.  When I move the map or zoom the map (moveend), I can use `queryRenderedFeatures` to get data of rendered mountains.  Here is my code;

```
    map.on('moveend', 'skiAreaPolygon', (e) => {

        const featuresRendered = map.queryRenderedFeatures(
            {layers: ['skiAreaPolygon']}
        );
        console.log(featuresRendered);
    }
```

I am using datatables to display the names of the mountains in a table below the map.  The way I have configured Datatables is to use a JSON file.  How can I ask Mapbox to return a JSON file with `queryRenderedFeatures`?  In the documentation, it says it returns a "GeoJSON Feature objects".

In my `console.log(featuresRendered);` output, it returns below.  Anyway to get this into a GeoJSON without numbers?  Also, what `rd` [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapbox feature object has method `.toJSON()` which converts feature to classic GeoJSON feature object (with some additional nonstandard attributes).

Your code could then look something like this:

```
map.on('moveend', 'skiAreaPolygon', (e) => {
  const featuresRendered = map.queryRenderedFeatures(
    {layers: ['skiAreaPolygon']}
  );
  featuresRendered.forEach((feature) => {
    var json = feature.toJSON();
    console.log(json);
  });
}
```